# How do I protect my registration input from users with SQL db?

Tags: java, sql

I'm new programmer trying to build an app and I'm using java (spring?) and community sql db. I have to get a username, pw and email from users then post to my DB what's a good way of protecting the db from shady inputs? I was thinking of doing like an if(username =/= string) do stuff but then I would either have to do that in my controller, or pass around value's to parts of my program that i don't want to be passing.

view:

```
<form   action= "Signup" method="POST" >
Choose a username: <input type ="text" name ="username">  <br>
Choose a password<input type ="password" name ="password" >  <br>
Enter your email: <input type ="text" name ="email"> <br>
<input type ="submit" value ="Sign up">  
</form>
```

my code then created an object with username,pw,email as it's variables and passes it to a writeToDB

```
try {
        Statement stmt = dbConnectionObject.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO signup (username, password, email) values ('" + username + "', '" + password
                + "', '" + email + "')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but im thinking this is bad practice right? can they enter something shady in instead of a username? Is there a standard practice to check username/pw/email?

Comment: a) Use a PreparedStatement  also b) do client side validation too.

Comment: **Never use string concatenation to build SQL commands!**